# Equivalent of codepad for recent versions of Ruby

Tags: ruby

What equivalents of codepad are there that run recent versions of Ruby?

I was trying to show that a code snippet [doesn't work](http://codepad.org/4WYIf6Nb), but codepad runs Ruby 1.8.6, so it's theoretically possible that the code doesn't work in 1.8.6 but works under 1.9.2.

I also tried using "Try Ruby", but you can't create anonymous or non-anonymous classes:

```
> H = Class­.new
=> #<NameError: uninitialized constant H>
> Class.new
=> #<TypeError: can't dump anonymous class #<Class:0x155468081>>
> class J
.. end
=> nil
> J
=> #<NameError: uninitialized constant J>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [ideone.com](http://ideone.com), running ruby-1.9.2 ([proof](http://ideone.com/TNIAn)).